# how to display the number of vowels in a list?

Tags: python

first, I need to write a program that displays the names of the planets in the list Planets in descending order by their position from the Sun.
then, I should rite a program that displays the names of the planets in the list Planets in ascending order by the number of vowels in planet name.

I have been able to do the first part. however, I couldn't the second part.

```
Planets = [("Mercury", 75, 1), ("Venus", 460, 2), ("Mars", 140, 4),
           ("Earth", 510, 3), ("Jupiter", 62000, 5), ("Neptune", 7640, 8),
           ("Saturn", 42700, 6), ("Uranus", 8100, 7)]


def main():
    Planets.sort(key=Sort_By_Position,reverse=True)
    print("The names of the planets in descending order by their position from the Sun: ")
    for i in Planets:
        print (i[0])

    print(" ")

    print("Planets in ascending order by the number of vowels in planet name: ")
    Planets.sort(key=vowel_count)
    for i in Planets:
        print(i[0])

def Sort_By_Position(Planets):
    return Planets[-1]

def vowel_count():


main()
```

I expect the program to show me the ascending order of planets by the number of vowels in planet name.

Comment: you didn’t implement a function to count vowels so why would you expect it to sort by vowels

Comment: Hi, StackOverflow doesn't exist to do your homework for you. That doesn't mean you can't ask questions about your homework, though. You are much more likely to get a useful answer if you at least tried to implement vowel counting in some way. e.g. try googling for functions to do it for at least one string, and then give a go at iterating it over your list. If that doesn't work, _ask specific questions about the problems that you encountered,_ rather than ask someone to provide the complete solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

here is solution

```
Planets = [("Mercury", 75, 1), ("Venus", 460, 2), ("Mars", 140, 4), ("Earth", 510, 3), ("Jupiter", 62000, 5), ("Neptune", 7640, 8), ("Saturn", 42700, 6), ("Uranus", 8100, 7)]

# decending order in order
new_pl=Planets.copy()
new_pl.sort(key=lambda x:x[2], reverse=True) # sorting on position value

print(new_pl)

"""
output
[('Neptune', 7640, 8), ('Uranus', 8100, 7), ('Saturn', 42700, 6), ('Jupiter', 62000, 5), ('Mars', 140, 4), ('Earth', 510, 3), ('Venus', 460, 2), ('Mercury', 75, 1)]
"""


# in no of vowels present
vowel = ['a','e','i','o','u']

# in vowels
def count(name):
    vowel = ['a','e','i','o','u']
    val=0
    for i in name.lower():
        if i in vowel:
            val+=1
    return val

new_pl_2=Planets.copy()

new_pl_2.sort(key=lambda x:count(x[0])) #sorting on count of vowels
print(new_pl_2)

"""
output

[('Mars', 140, 4), ('Mercury', 75, 1), ('Venus', 460, 2), ('Earth', 510, 3), ('Saturn', 42700, 6), ('Jupiter', 62000, 5), ('Neptune', 7640, 8), ('Uranus', 8100, 7)]
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you were able to do the first part so you are essentially only asking about the second part. The following example should help get you pointed in the right direction:

```
>>> planets = ['Mercury','Venus','Earth','Mars','Neptune','Jupiter','Saturn','Uranus']
>>> vowels = ('a','e','i','o','u')
>>> name_counts = []
>>> for name in planets:
...     count = sum([1 for letter in name if letter.lower() in vowels])
...     name_counts.append((name,count))
... 
>>> print(sorted(name_counts, key=lambda x: x[1]))
[('Mars', 1), ('Mercury', 2), ('Venus', 2), ('Earth', 2), ('Saturn', 2), ('Neptune', 3), ('Jupiter', 3), ('Uranus', 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one line using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
def vowel_count(elem):
 return len([x for x in elem[0] if x in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')])
```

`elem[0]` contains the name of the planet you are iterating over. When you iterate over a string (`x in elem[0]`), it will iterate each individual character in that string. For example, `'Earth'` becomes `['E', 'a', 'r', 't', 'h']`.

From there, we can simply filter the list comprehension to only contain vowels (`if x.lower() in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')`) and return the length of the comprehension, which is fed back to the `sort` method.